# Not able to select few cells in collection view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am setting a collection view embedded in container view, with one section and 'n' cells in that section. I have configured flow layout, vertical scrolling and cell size is adjusted such that i will have only two columns and n/2 rows. Sometimes selection of all cells are fine but most of the time I am not able to select any of the cells in second column.

Comment: Can you add the code here. @Ash1234

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your UICollectionView do not fall outside of your container view after the layoutConstraints have been applied.  You can check this by setting Clip Subviews to true on your Container view in storyboard.

Comment: I have set Clip Subviews to true, but it dint solve my problem.